Computing Physical and Risk-Neutral Moments in a Model-Based Fashion
In Christoffersen et al. (2013), the authors state that it is possible to compute both physical and risk-neutral moments separately in a model-based fashion. Some examples of option pricing models that can do these are Heston (1993) and Bates (2000).
I am quite surprised because even in Model-Free implementation (such as in the VIX methodology), the outputs are risk-neutral. How is it possible that models are able to produce physical moments?
To be specific, I think the authors are referring to physical skewness and kurtosis.
